# How does color gradient works?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement below picture in my code but it doesn't work. It only shows red color on all sides. I'm using line renderer and color gradient.

[image]

```
 void Start()
{
    lineGeneratorPrefab = new GameObject();

    DrawLine();
}




private void DrawLine()
{
    GameObject myLine = new GameObject();
    myLine.transform.position = start;
    myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));     
    lr.positionCount = 4;
    lr.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(-2, 0, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(2, 0, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(2, new Vector3(2, -2, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(3, new Vector3(-2, -2, 0));
    lr.loop = true;


    Gradient gradient = new Gradient();
    gradient.SetKeys(
        new GradientColorKey[]
        {
            new GradientColorKey(Color.red, 0.25f),
            new GradientColorKey(Color.blue, 0.25f),
            new GradientColorKey(Color.green, 0.25f),
            new GradientColorKey(Color.yellow, 0.25f)
        },
            new GradientAlphaKey[] { new GradientAlphaKey(1.0f, 0.0f) }
        );
    lr.colorGradient = gradient;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of [GradientColorKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GradientColorKey.html) is the index between [0,1],

so you may modify the GradientColorKey array like:

```
new GradientColorKey[]
    {
        new GradientColorKey(Color.red, 0.00f),
        new GradientColorKey(Color.red, 0.24f),
        new GradientColorKey(Color.blue, 0.25f),
        new GradientColorKey(Color.blue, 0.49f),
        new GradientColorKey(Color.green, 0.50f),
        new GradientColorKey(Color.green, 0.74f),
        new GradientColorKey(Color.yellow, 0.75f),
        new GradientColorKey(Color.yellow, 1.00f)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks men it works. My problem now is how to refine its edges.